# Groovy How to replace the exact match word in a String

Tags: groovy

Groovy How to replace the exact match word in a String.

I wanted to replace the exact matched word in a given string in Groovy. and when i tried the below am not getting the exact matched word

```
def str="My Name is Richards and Richardson"
log.info(str)
str=str.replace("Richards","Praveen")
log.info("After"+str)
```

Output after executing the above

My Name is Richards and Richardson
AfterMy Name is Praveen and Praveenon

Am Looking for the output like : AfterMy Name is Praveen and Richardson

I tried the boundaries \b
str=str.replace("\bRichards\b","Praveen")
which is in Java and its not working. Looks \b is ba backslash escape sequence in the Groovy

can someone help

```
def str="My Name is Richards and Richardson"
log.info(str)
str=str.replace("Richards","Praveen")
log.info("After"+str)
```

expecting:AfterMy Name is Praveen and Richardson

Comment: Is your requirement to replace `"Richards"` with`"Praveen"`, unless `"Richards"` is followed by a non-whitespace character?

Comment: Yes , Requirement is to replace "Richards" with "Praveen"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boundaries (`/b`) will not work with [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) because the method argument does not accept a regular expression pattern but a simple string literal.

You have two options to get the expected outcome:

1. Instead of using  [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) you can use [`String::replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). As the method name suggests it will replace only the first occurrence of the `Richards` substring leaving the `Richardson` as is.

   ```
   str = str.replaceFirst("Richards", "Praveen")
   ```
2. Instead of using [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) you can use [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), in opposite to [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) it supports regular expressions so you can use word boundaries tokens

   ```
   str = str.replaceAll("\\bRichards\\b","Praveen")
   ```

**Mind the double slashes!**

Also, according to the [`String::replaceAll` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see [`Matcher.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)). Use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

Comment: This one has worked for me and thanks a lot for the solution . i have used the replaceAll as it will  Dynamically suiting to all requirement. Unfortunately i  couldnt cast a Vote as i would need 15 reputations to cast a Vote :( Am a new user

Comment: In a comment above @PraveenThirumoorthy answered "Yes" to the question "Is your requirement to replace "Richards" with"Praveen", unless "Richards" is followed by a non-whitespace character?".  I think the solution proposed here will do the substitution even if `"Richards"` is followed by something like a comma or a period.  Are those generally considered whitespace?